# Azure Function Deployment failing because function.json is wrong

Tags: azure, azure-functions, continuous-deployment, automated-deployment

When I deploy an Azure Function from Visual Studio, the function.json file is always incorrect. An example of the function.json file is the following for a queue triggered function:

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.12",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
{
  "type": "queueTrigger",
  "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
  "queueName": "queue",
  "name": "myQueueItem"
}
],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/x.dll",
  "entryPoint": "x"
}
```

The correct function.json in order for the function to work in azure is:

```
{
      "bindings": [
{
  "type": "queueTrigger",
  "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
  "direction" : "in",
  "queueName": "queue",
  "name": "myQueueItem"
}
],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/x.dll",
  "entryPoint": "x"
}
```

Is there any solution to automated deployments/ Visual Studio deployments that would do this automatically? Currently I am editing all the function.json files every deployment. Any solutions or workarounds would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by `the function.json file is wrong`. The 1st one looks ok. Have you found any issue with the 1st one ?

Comment: The first one would not work when deployed to azure. I have tried this many times, each deployment I need to edit the function.json to the format of the 2nd file

Comment: I've been using the functions sdk quite a lot and it is working fine. Are you targetting azure functions runtime v1/v2 ? .net core or .net framework ? Have you tried to get latest nuget package `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` ?

Comment: Currently using azure functions runtime v1

I have the most recent nuget package for Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions

Comment: @Thomas Im using .net framework as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @Thomas, have tested v1 queue trigger template with `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.12` and latest `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.22`, `function.json` generated by VS does work.

Actually two `function.json` both work on Azure, those two line below are used to tell `function.json` is generated by VS and not recommended to be modified after deployment.

```
"generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.22",
"configurationSource": "attributes",
```

> The first one would not work

Function execution result may not be shown instantly, you could go to `https://functionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and navigate to `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\function\{FunctionName}` to check log files.

Also you can visit `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Host` to detect detailed host logs.

If you are still troubled, you could elaborate `would not work` with details and show us your code.

Comment: How about a queue trigger template with an output binding as well? The deployments I make don't create an output binding

Comment: @DarthVeder This is by design, output binding is not built into `function.json`, only trigger info is available.